# Почему определение "Класс состоит из полей и методов" не является полным?

Tags: c++, ооп

Почему определение "Класс состоит из полей и методов" не является полным? Что еще может быть составной частью класса?

Comment: Это все зависит от того, как определяется класс, и как определяются понятия поля и метода.:)

Comment: Ваш вопрос совершенно не корректно пометили как дубликат. На самом деле ваш вопрос не является дубликатом вопроса, указанного в ссылке, так как неизвестно, как определяется класс в вашем случае и, например, какой язык программирования используется, если это определение класса связано с каким-то языком программирования.

Comment: вопрос задан был в контексте с++

Comment: Добавил метку языка, предложил переоткрытие.

Comment: А отвечать-то будет кто? Что имеется в виду? Статические члены/методы? Иерархия предков? Таблица виртуальных функций?

Comment: Шла бы речь об объекте, то состояние и поведение - исчерпывающий ответ. А классов ведь как ложек, не существует...

Comment: Если совсем придираться, в контексте с++, то методов класса нет. Есть функции класса.
Но если хочется уточнений - скажите, где вопрос был взят. Если с методички, то лучше там прочитать правильный ответ.

Comment: Может быть, имеются ввиду конструкторы и деструкторы как особый вид методов?

Answer (score 1):

> Что еще может быть составной частью класса?

Смысл. Поля (состояние) и методы (поведение) класса объединены единым смыслом в рамках выбранной модели абстрагирования (то есть, принципом выявления сущностей задачи)